# SQL Multiple columns will have the same data - How to shorten query

Tags: sql

I have a few columns where the data will be the same results.

```
DECLARE @Alias AS nvarchar(15)
SET @Alias = '%MyAlias%'

SELECT TOP 10 
*
FROM 
    ATSStaging..LIR_Amendment
WHERE 
    (AppliedByUser LIKE @Alias
    OR ModifiedByUser LIKE @Alias
    OR CreatedByUser LIKE @Alias)
```

Rather than searching all 3 columns to chekc for the same value is there a way to shorten this?

Something like:

```
WHERE
(AppliedByUser OR ModifiedbyUser OR CreatedByUser LIKE @Alias
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can trick it in your case with:

```
WHERE
concat(AppliedByUser, ModifiedbyUser, CreatedByUser) LIKE @Alias
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* concatenate the values together and then use `like`:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM  ATSStaging..LIR_Amendment
WHERE (AppliedByUser + '|' + ModifiedByUser + '|' + CreatedByUser) LIKE @Alias;
```

I wouldn't recommend this as a general solution.  But, your `like` patterns starts with a wildcard so your query would require a full table scan anyway.  The concatenation probably incurs a small amount of additional overhead, versus the `or` (which should stop at the first column that matches).  You might find that a full-text index gives you much improved functionality and performance.

Answer (score 0):

In this **specific** case (because you are using a LIKE '%match%' expression), you can use concatenation:

```
WHERE AppliedByUser + ModifiedbyUser + CreatedByUser LIKE @Alias
```

In general, no: butthere's nothing really wrong with the query the way you had it originally.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the DBMS that you are using you may use FULLTEXTSEARCH.

In SQL Server for example, that would mean creating a indexed view containing the data you want to search in and then a FULLTEXT index on that column.

This will provide the best performance as patter matching doesn't perform very well over normal indexes.